# What's the difference between "while 1" and "while True"?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I've seen two ways to create an infinite loop in Python:

1. ```
   while 1:
       do_something()
   ```
2. ```
   while True:
       do_something()
   ```

Is there any difference between these? Is one more pythonic than the other?

Comment: maybe a infinte loop isn't pythonic ? (see balpha)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Fundamentally it doesn't matter, such minutiae doesn't really affect whether something is 'pythonic' or not.

If you're interested in trivia however, there are some differences.

1. The [builtin boolean type didn't exist till Python 2.3](http://www.python.org/doc/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-bool.html) so code that was intended to run on ancient versions tends to use the `while 1:` form. You'll see it in the standard library, for instance.
2. The True and False builtins are [not reserved words prior to Python 3](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax) so could be assigned to, changing their value. This helps with the case above because code could do `True = 1` for backwards compatibility, but means that the name `True` needs to be looked up in the globals dictionary every time it is used.
3. Because of the above restriction, the bytecode the two versions compile to is different in Python 2 as there's an optimisation for constant integers that it can't use for `True`. Because Python can tell when compiling the `1` that it's always non-zero, it removes the conditional jump and doesn't load the constant at all:

   ```
   >>> import dis
   >>> def while_1():
   ...     while 1:
   ...         pass
   ...
   >>> def while_true():
   ...     while True:
   ...         pass
   ...
   >>> dis.dis(while_1)
     2           0 SETUP_LOOP               5 (to 8)

     3     >>    3 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
                 6 POP_TOP
                 7 POP_BLOCK
           >>    8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
                11 RETURN_VALUE
   >>> dis.dis(while_true)
     2           0 SETUP_LOOP              12 (to 15)
           >>    3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
                 6 JUMP_IF_FALSE            4 (to 13)
                 9 POP_TOP

     3          10 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
           >>   13 POP_TOP
                14 POP_BLOCK
           >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
                18 RETURN_VALUE
   ```

So, `while True:` is a little easier to read, and `while 1:` is a bit kinder to old versions of Python. As you're unlikely to need to run on Python 2.2 these days or need to worry about the bytecode count of your loops, the former is marginally preferable.

Comment: I would like to point out that, *in my humble opinion*, the most pythonic way of doing something is to NOT fret about details like this. While the post is absolutely interesting and informative, and I do appreciate that, I stand by the claim that `while True:` is more pythonic. At least the way I interpret the odd term *pythonic*, your mileage may vary.

Comment: You can still redefine `True` in 3.x if you try really hard. In 3.0, `import builtins; builtins.__dict__['True'] = 0` will do it; in 3.3, you have to get a lot more creative, but it's still possible. If worst comes to worst, you can always `ctypes` your way into the C API (or equivalent for other implementations). The fun thing is that the compiler _assumes_ you can't do it, so some expressions will get compiled out, while others will use your new value, in an implementation-/version-dependent way. And if you can find a good use for all that… you can probably find better ways to use your time…

Answer (score 12):

The most pythonic way will always be the most readable. Use `while True:`

Comment: "while 1:" is quite different from "for(;;)" :-)

Comment: @nomemory: The question was about "Pythonic" -- which has little or nothing to do with C programmers.  If you want something readable for C programmers, please use C.

Comment: @S.Lott : what I was trying to say is that readability is something very relative.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't really matter. Neither is hard to read or understand, though personally I'd always use `while True`, which is a bit more explicit.

More generally, a whole lot of while–break loops people write in Python could be something else. Sometimes I see people write `i = 0; while True: i += 1 ...`, which can be replaced with `for i in itertools.count()` and people writing `while True: foo = fun() if foo is None: break` when this can be written `for foo in iter(fun, None)`, which requires learning but has less boilerplate and opportunity for silly mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Neither.

Both of them mean I have to scan the code looking for the `break`, instead of being able to see the stop condition right where it belongs.

I try to avoid this kind of thing wherever possible, and if it's not possible, let the code speak for itself like this:

```
while not found_answer:
    check_number += 1
    if check_number == 42:
        found_answer = True
```

**Edit:** It seems that the word "avoid" above wasn't clear enough. Using a basically infinite loop and leaving it from somewhere within the loop (using `break`) **should usually be avoided altogether**. Sometimes that isn't possible. In that case, I like to use something like the code above, *which, however, still represents the same concept* –  **the above code is nothing more than a compromise** – but at least, I can show the purpose of the loop *at the beginning* – just like I wouldn't call a  function `do_something_with_args(*args)`.

Comment: But in your code, you just have to scan the code for `found_answer = True`.

Comment: I don't see how this is preferable. Often the reason for using a `break` is that the stop condition can't be easily or efficiently expressed. If you literally mean use a variable like `found_answer` then you have to scan for that rather than `break` - and in general you'll still need a `continue` instead of the `break` to make it exit the loop.

Comment: @Mike Graham: Yes, and I said I like to avoid this at all. If I use it, I try to make things clear (i.e. readable) by giving the boolean a name that explains *what* it is that makes this loop stop.

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: But unlike `True`, `not found_answer` or `not received_quit_command` tells something to the reader of the code.

Comment: @balpha: That's a fair point, but I can't help feeling that you're introducing a new variable and adding an extra conditional evaluation just to make the intent of the loop clearer, when all you really need is a simple comment at the start?

Comment: @Scott Griffiths: ... and at the break statement(s). But yes, that might be a matter of taste; I like to use function and variable names as "comments" where I can; but your point is valid. My point, still, is **either way, try to do something entirely different**. I really fail to understand why this isn't clear from my answer.

Answer (score 3):

IMO the second option is more *obvious*.

If you could get rid of the `while` and write more compact code, that might be more pythonic.
For example:

```
# Get the even numbers in the range 1..10
# Version 1
l = []
n = 1
while 1:
    if n % 2 == 0: l.append(n)
    n += 1
    if n > 10: break
print l

# Version 2
print [i for i in range(1, 11) if i % 2 == 0]

# Version 3
print range(2, 11, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is mostly a matter of style. Both should be easily understandable as an infinite loop.

However, personally I prefer the second option. That's because it just takes a mental micro-step less to understand, especially for programmers without C background.

Answer (score 2):

The first one will work also in those early versions where `True` is not yet defined.

Comment: At this point, once you program for Python 3, maintaining backwards compatibility is pretty much moot anyways.

Comment: I wonder which was the last version of Python where True wasn't supported?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an algorithm that is suppose to terminate in a finite time, I would recommend this, which is always safer than `while True`:

```
maxiter = 1000
for i in xrange(maxiter):
   # your code
   # on success:
     break
else:
   # that algorithm has not finished in maxiter steps! do something accordingly
```

Comment: I disagree in this respect and there is a prominent school to make criteria as sharp as possible. If you expect a value to be zero, say so "== 0" and don't rely on "<= 1", since being -1 may indicate completely unexpected branch of preceeding processing; an endless loop will surely be detected by someone, while the code following else still has to ensure this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second expression is more explicit, and thus more [pythonic](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is only a matter of style, any programming beginner will understand either option.

But the second option will only work if `True` wasn't assigned to `False`, which was possible until Python 3:

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
```

Comment: That's a good observation, but anyone who does this on a project with other devs will almost certainly be beaten to within an inch of their life...

Answer (score 0):

The better way is "while True" with a conditional break out of the loop.