# while (1) vs. while(True) -- Why is there a difference (in python 2 bytecode)?

Tags: python

Intrigued by this question about infinite loops in perl: [while (1) Vs. for (;;) Is there a speed difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference), I decided to run a similar comparison in python. I expected that the compiler would generate the same byte code for `while(True): pass` and `while(1): pass`, but this is actually not the case in python2.7.

The following script:

```
import dis

def while_one():
    while 1:
        pass

def while_true():
    while True:
        pass

print("while 1")
print("----------------------------")
dis.dis(while_one)

print("while True")
print("----------------------------")
dis.dis(while_true)
```

produces the following results:

```
while 1
----------------------------
  4           0 SETUP_LOOP               3 (to 6)

  5     >>    3 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>    6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
while True
----------------------------
  8           0 SETUP_LOOP              12 (to 15)
        >>    3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              6 JUMP_IF_FALSE            4 (to 13)
              9 POP_TOP             

  9          10 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   13 POP_TOP             
             14 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Using `while True` is noticeably more complicated. Why is this?

In other contexts, python acts as though `True` equals 1:

```
>>> True == 1
True

>>> True + True
2
```

Why does `while` distinguish the two?

I noticed that python3 does evaluate the statements using identical operations:

```
while 1
----------------------------
  4           0 SETUP_LOOP               3 (to 6) 

  5     >>    3 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3 
        >>    6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              9 RETURN_VALUE         
while True
----------------------------
  8           0 SETUP_LOOP               3 (to 6) 

  9     >>    3 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3 
        >>    6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Is there a change in python3 to the way booleans are evaluated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "while 1" and "while True"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261987/whats-the-difference-between-while-1-and-while-true)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `True` is not a keyword, but just a [built-in global constant](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#True) that is defined to 1 in the `bool` type. Therefore the interpreter still has to load the contents of `True`.  In other words, `True` is reassignable:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 21:12:11) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True = 4
>>> True
4
```

---

In Python 3.x [it truly becomes a keyword](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and a real constant:

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79147, Jul 19 2010, 21:03:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True = 4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: assignment to keyword
```

thus the interpreter can replace the `while True:` loop with an infinite loop.

Comment: @M.H: AFAIK, it was an expedient to get the keyword into the language.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.3.html#pep-285-a-boolean-type and http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/ for some of the history.

Comment: Does this mean `while 1` and `while True` are identical in Python 3?

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro Yes.

Answer (score 22):

It isn't quite right, to call it an "infinite loop"

> thus the interpreter can replace the while True: loop with an infinite loop.

because one can still break out of such a `while True:` loop. But  such a loop's `else` clause would never be accessed in Python 3.

And Python 3's simplifying of the value lookup for `True` makes it run just as quickly as `while 1` in Python 2.

## Performance Comparison

Demonstrating the difference in time for a somewhat nontrivial while loop:

### Setup

```
def while1():
    x = 0
    while 1:
        x += 1
        if x == 10:
            break
            
def whileTrue():
    x = 0
    while True:
        x += 1
        if x == 10:
            break
```

### Python 2

```
>>> import timeit
>>> min(timeit.repeat(while1))
0.49712109565734863
>>> min(timeit.repeat(whileTrue))
0.756627082824707
```

### Python 3

```
>>> import timeit
>>> min(timeit.repeat(while1))
0.6462970309949014
>>> min(timeit.repeat(whileTrue))
0.6450748789939098
```

## Explanation

To explain the difference, in Python 2:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> 'True' in keyword.kwlist
False
```

but in Python 3:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> 'True' in keyword.kwlist
True
>>> True = 'true?'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
```

Since `True` is a keyword in Python 3, the interpreter doesn't have to look up the value to see if someone replaced it with some other value. But since one can assign `True` to another value in Python 2, the interpreter has to look it up every time.

## Conclusion for Python 2

If you have a tight, long-running loop in Python 2, you probably should use `while 1:` instead of `while True:`.

## Conclusion for Python 3

Use `while True:` if you have no condition for breaking out of your loop.

Answer (score 7):

This is a 7-year-old question that already has a great answer, but a misconception in the question, which isn't addressed in any of the answers, makes it potentially confusing for some of the other questions marked as duplicates.

> In other contexts, python acts as though True equals 1:

```
>>> True == 1
True

>>> True + True
2
```

> Why does while distinguish the two?

In fact, `while` isn't doing anything different here at all. It distinguishes `1` and `True` in exactly the same way that the `+` example does.

---

Here's 2.7:

```
>>> dis.dis('True == 1')
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis('True == 1')
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now compare:

```
>>> dis.dis('1 + 1')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

It's emitting a `LOAD_GLOBAL (True)` for each `True`, and there's nothing the optimizer can do with a global. So, `while` distinguishes `1` and `True` for the exact same reason that `+` does. (And `==` doesn't distinguish them because the optimizer doesn't optimize out comparisons.)

---

Now compare 3.6:

```
>>> dis.dis('True == 1')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis('True + True')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here, it's emitting a `LOAD_CONST (True)` for the keyword, which the optimizer *can* take advantage of. So, `True + 1` *doesn't* distinguish, for exactly the same reason `while True` doesn't. (And `==` still doesn't distinguish them because the optimizer doesn't optimize out comparisons.)

---

Meanwhile, if the code isn't optimized out, the interpreter ends up treating `True` and `1` exactly the same in all three of these cases. `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and inherits most of its methods from `int`, and `True` has an internal integer value of 1. So, whether you're doing a `while` test (`__bool__` in 3.x, `__nonzero__` in 2.x), a comparison (`__eq__`), or arithmetic (`__add__`), you're calling the same method whether you use `True` or `1`.