# While True or while 1?

Tags: python, interpreter, bytecode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [while (1) Vs. for while(True) — Why is there a difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815359/while-1-vs-for-whiletrue-why-is-there-a-difference)

I see sometimes in other people code "while 1" instead of "while True".
I think using True is more pythonic, but I wanted to check if there is
any difference in practice.

So I tried to do the following, and the result is surprising.  For what
I can see it looks like the interpreter can optimize away the 1 boolean
conversion while it doesn't with the True, the opposite of what I
supposed.

Anyone can explain me why is that, or maybe is my conclusion wrong?

```
def f1():
    while 1:
        pass

def f2():
    while True:
        pass

In [10]: dis.dis(f)
2           0 SETUP_LOOP               3 (to 6)

3     >>    3 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
      >>    6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            9 RETURN_VALUE

In [9]: dis.dis(f1)
2           0 SETUP_LOOP              10 (to 13)
      >>    3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
            6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

3           9 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
      >>   12 POP_BLOCK
      >>   13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: it never really matters because presumably the real code doesn't do pass. So prefer readability.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler can't optimize away the reference to `True` because, unfortunately, in python 2 I can do this:

```
True = []
if not True:
    print "oops" # :-(
```

Luckily, in python 3.2 I get `SyntaxError: assignment to keyword`.