# While 1 vs While True. Which one is more pythonic?

Tags: python, loops, syntax

I've seen both ways of writing the same in Python:

```
while 1: 
   # do something here
```

and

```
while True:
   # do something here
```

**Which one is more pythonic?**

*I already know that `True` [is already a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815359/while-1-vs-for-whiletrue-why-is-there-a-difference), [the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953439/while-true-or-while-1), etc., but I'm asking about which one is more pythonic*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no practical difference.  `1` and `True` are equal in python, and this is guaranteed in future too, so could use whichever you like the look of best.

As for which is pythonic, I think it's pythonic to avoid these kind of loops altogether, except in those rare cases where you do actually intend to have an infinite loop.

You can virtually always write them with an explicit terminating condition instead of break statement(s), and *explicit is better than implicit*.

---

Both are used in the standard libraries with approximately equal frequency.  96 occurrences for `while True`:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7$ grep -rn "while True:"
_abcoll.py:292:            while True:
_abcoll.py:478:            while True:
_abcoll.py:531:            while True:
argparse.py:1807:            while True:
base64.py:287:    while True:
base64.py:302:    while True:
calendar.py:162:        while True:
chunk.py:28:while True:
chunk.py:34:    while True:
codecs.py:458:        while True:
codecs.py:529:        while True:
ConfigParser.py:478:        while True:
decimal.py:2141:            while True:
decimal.py:2331:            while True:
decimal.py:2681:        while True:
decimal.py:2990:            while True:
decimal.py:3124:        while True:
decimal.py:3205:            while True:
decimal.py:5695:            while True:
difflib.py:1466:        while True:
difflib.py:1556:        while True:
difflib.py:1573:        while True:
difflib.py:1580:        while True:
filecmp.py:67:        while True:
fractions.py:245:        while True:
gzip.py:202:            while True:
gzip.py:208:            while True:
gzip.py:248:                while True:
gzip.py:502:        while True:
httplib.py:273:        while True:
httplib.py:406:        while True:
httplib.py:411:            while True:
httplib.py:572:        while True:
httplib.py:610:        while True:
httplib.py:747:        while True:
locale.py:134:            while True:
mailbox.py:217:            while True:
mailbox.py:534:        while True:
mailbox.py:652:                while True:
mailbox.py:814:        while True:
mailbox.py:850:        while True:
mailbox.py:856:                while True:
mailbox.py:1221:        while True:
mailbox.py:1227:        while True:
mailbox.py:1246:        while True:
mailbox.py:1251:        while True:
mailbox.py:1279:        while True:
mailbox.py:1342:            while True:
mailbox.py:1352:                while True:
mailbox.py:1359:                while True:
mailbox.py:1364:            while True:
mailbox.py:1385:            while True:
mailbox.py:1395:            while True:
mimetypes.py:243:            while True:
pdb.py:1312:    while True:
pickletools.py:1841:    while True:
posixpath.py:299:    while True:
pty.py:146:    while True:
pyclbr.py:196:                    while True:
pyclbr.py:284:    while True:
pyclbr.py:308:    while True:
py_compile.py:146:        while True:
pydoc.py:537:        while True:
pydoc.py:1762:        while True:
_pyio.py:559:        while True:
_pyio.py:953:            while True:
_pyio.py:1013:            while True:
_pyio.py:1896:        while True:
sets.py:356:            while True:
shlex.py:123:        while True:
socket.py:349:            while True:
socket.py:372:            while True:
socket.py:427:                while True:
socket.py:445:            while True:
socket.py:474:            while True:
socket.py:514:        while True:
SocketServer.py:153:    while True:
ssl.py:196:            while True:
subprocess.py:476:    while True:
sysconfig.py:406:    while True:
tarfile.py:529:            while True:
tarfile.py:534:            while True:
tarfile.py:566:            while True:
tarfile.py:836:            while True:
tarfile.py:859:        while True:
tarfile.py:902:        while True:
tarfile.py:1168:            while True:
tarfile.py:1384:        while True:
tarfile.py:1579:                while True:
tarfile.py:2317:        while True:
tarfile.py:2379:        while True:
tarfile.py:2508:        while True:
threading.py:255:                while True:
uu.py:105:        while True:
_weakrefset.py:97:        while True:
zipfile.py:579:        while True:
```

And 116 occurrences for `while 1`.  Note that older code is more likely to have this form because `bool` wasn't always around in early python.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7$ grep -rn "while 1:" *.py
aifc.py:309:        while 1:
aifc.py:962:        while 1:
audiodev.py:252:    while 1:
binhex.py:257:    while 1:
binhex.py:265:    while 1:
binhex.py:295:            while 1:
binhex.py:377:        while 1:
binhex.py:481:    while 1:
binhex.py:492:        while 1:
cgi.py:251:        while 1:
cgi.py:683:        while 1:
cgi.py:696:        while 1:
cgi.py:729:        while 1:
code.py:227:        while 1:
compileall.py:141:            while 1:
DocXMLRPCServer.py:41:        while 1:
fpformat.py:141:        while 1:
ftplib.py:199:            while 1:
ftplib.py:407:        while 1:
ftplib.py:431:        while 1:
ftplib.py:462:        while 1:
ftplib.py:484:        while 1:
ftplib.py:691:                while 1:
ftplib.py:709:                while 1:
ftplib.py:731:                while 1:
ftplib.py:747:                while 1:
ftplib.py:904:        while 1:
getpass.py:97:    while 1:
heapq.py:346:    while 1:
heapq.py:348:            while 1:
imaplib.py:864:        while 1:
imaplib.py:987:        while 1:
_LWPCookieJar.py:111:            while 1:
mailbox.py:2021:        while 1:
mailbox.py:2039:        while 1:
mailbox.py:2050:        while 1:
mailbox.py:2109:        while 1:
mailbox.py:2117:        while 1:
mailbox.py:2164:        while 1:
mailbox.py:2172:        while 1:
mailcap.py:63:    while 1:
markupbase.py:269:        while 1:
markupbase.py:323:        while 1:
markupbase.py:345:            while 1:
markupbase.py:358:        while 1:
mhlib.py:305:        while 1:
mhlib.py:616:            while 1:
mhlib.py:915:    while 1:
mhlib.py:920:            while 1:
mimetools.py:240:    while 1:
mimetools.py:247:    while 1:
mimetypes.py:213:        while 1:
mimify.py:86:        while 1:
mimify.py:98:    while 1:
mimify.py:111:    while 1:
mimify.py:135:    while 1:
mimify.py:164:    while 1:
mimify.py:241:    while 1:
mimify.py:266:    while 1:
mimify.py:292:    while 1:
mimify.py:315:    while 1:
mimify.py:390:            while 1:
mimify.py:407:        while 1:
_MozillaCookieJar.py:58:            while 1:
multifile.py:15:while 1:
multifile.py:114:        while 1:
netrc.py:38:        while 1:
netrc.py:58:                while 1:
netrc.py:73:            while 1:
nntplib.py:239:            while 1:
nntplib.py:559:        while 1:
nntplib.py:583:        while 1:
os.py:545:            while 1:
pdb.py:40:    while 1:
pickle.py:856:            while 1:
platform.py:166:    while 1:
platform.py:966:    while 1:
quopri.py:70:    while 1:
quopri.py:128:    while 1:
random.py:394:        while 1:
random.py:464:        while 1:
random.py:517:            while 1:
random.py:540:            while 1:
re.py:310:        while 1:
rfc822.py:148:        while 1:
shlex.py:287:    while 1:
shutil.py:48:    while 1:
site.py:424:        while 1:
smtplib.py:352:        while 1:
smtplib.py:847:    while 1:
sre_parse.py:307:    while 1:
sre_parse.py:325:    while 1:
sre_parse.py:393:    while 1:
sre_parse.py:406:                while 1:
sre_parse.py:425:            while 1:
sre_parse.py:536:                        while 1:
sre_parse.py:549:                        while 1:
sre_parse.py:573:                    while 1:
sre_parse.py:600:                    while 1:
sre_parse.py:640:                while 1:
sre_parse.py:708:    while 1:
sre_parse.py:718:                    while 1:
telnetlib.py:587:        while 1:
telnetlib.py:608:        while 1:
telnetlib.py:616:        while 1:
telnetlib.py:732:        while 1:
tokenize.py:286:    while 1:                                   # loop over lines in stream
urllib.py:266:                while 1:
urlparse.py:282:    while 1:
wave.py:135:        while 1:
weakref.py:153:        while 1:
weakref.py:359:        while 1:
xdrlib.py:214:        while 1:
xmllib.py:187:        while 1:
xmlrpclib.py:1461:        while 1:
zipfile.py:1095:            while 1:
```

Comment: Maybe I'm reading you too literally here, but if it's "the same object" then `1 is True` should evaluate to `True`, but it does not.

Comment: Thanks, you're right that's very poorly worded on my part.  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for editing your answer and including those matches! `;)`