# How to get user input repeatly until i want to quit?

Tags: python, user-input

I want to get user input for multiple times and store the input data together in a string until input "quit" to quit from input. I think a for loop can work but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input("Enter something:")
    if user_input == "quit":
        break
```

Comment: castorInGT asked "store the input data together in a string", you are not doing that in your code...

Comment: Note: In Python 3, raw_input() has been renamed to input(): http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
input_string = ''
while 1:
    input = raw_input('Add to string: ')
    if input == 'quit': break
    input_string += input
```

Comment: thanks! so what does "while True" or "while 1" mean?

Comment: @casterInGT it means loop forever

Comment: @casterInGT: as thenoviceoof said, it means loop forever, until input 'quit' breakes this infinite loop. 'While True' and 'While 1' are (almost) the same, if you want to know further details, please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815359/while-1-vs-for-whiletrue-why-is-there-a-difference

Comment: how do i prevent from adding "quit" to the input_string?

Comment: with this code, 'quit' will NOT be added to 'input_string' because the code will stop ('break') BEFORE 'quit' would get added to 'input_string'
'break' immidiately stops the loop and ignores whatever code is coming afterwards INSIDE the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    input = raw_input('Prompt')
    print(input)
    if input == 'quit':
        break
```

Comment: This isn't valid Python syntax; you can't do inline assignments like that.

Comment: @DSM.. I didn't knew that.. Is there no way to make that work??

Comment: Modified it to make it correct..

Comment: No, there's no real way to get it to work in a C-like way (although you could write a class to get most of the behaviour.)  Incidentally, using semicolons at the end of lines isn't usual Python style.

Comment: @DSM. Yeah that I know.. Added semi-colon by mistake.. Out of habit of coding in Java..