# Dice rolling simulator in Python

Tags: python-3.x, simulator, dice

I want to write a program that rolls a dice. Now this is what I have :

```
import random
print("You rolled",random.randint(1,6))
```

And I also want to be able to do something like this:

```
print("Do you want to roll again? Y/N")
```

and then if I press Y it rolls again and if I press N I quit the app. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12608654/198633

Comment: Hi, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 13):

Let's walk through the process:
You already know what you need to generate random numbers.

1. `import random` (or you could be more specific and say `from random import randint`, because we only need `randint` in this program)
2. As you've already said it; `print("You rolled",random.randint(1,6))` "rolls the dice".
   but it does it only once, so you need a loop to repeat it. A [while loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) is calling to us.
3. You need to check if the user inputs `Y`. And you can simply do it with `"Y" in input()`.

code version 1.

```
import random
repeat = True
while repeat:
    print("You rolled",random.randint(1,6))
    print("Do you want to roll again? Y/N")
    repeat = "Y" in input()
```

code version 1.1 (A little better)

```
from random import randint
repeat = True
while repeat:
    print("You rolled",randint(1,6))
    print("Do you want to roll again?")
    repeat = ("y" or "yes") in input().lower()
```

In this code, the user is free to use strings like `yEs`, `y`, `yes`, `YES` and ... to continue the loop.

Now remember, in version 1.1, since I used `from random import randint` instead of `import random`, I don't need to say `random.randint(1, 6)` and simply `radint(1,6)` will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = "yes"
 roll_again = raw_input

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
    print ("Rolling the dices...")
    print ("The values are....")
    print (random.randint(min, max))
    print (random.randint(min, max))

    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dices again?")
```

Comment: You should add some explanations, since code-only answers are considered as low-quality here.

Answer (score -1):

This is for python 3

```
import random
repeat="Y"
while repeat == "Y":
   print("Rolling the dice")
   print(random.randint(1,6))

repeat =input("Do you wanna roll again Y/N?")
if repeat=="Y":
    continue
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the existing answers, so you should elaborate what makes it better. Also, code-only answers are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score -1):

I just started learning Python three days ago, but this is what I came up with for Python 3, and it works:

```
import random

question = input('Would you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')

while question != 'n':
    if question == 'y':
        die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
        die2 = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(die1, die2)
        question = input('Would you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')
    else:
        print('Invalid response. Please type "y" or "n".')
        question = input('Would you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')        

print('Good-bye!')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint
ques = input('Do you want to dice Y/N : ')

while ques.upper() == 'Y':
    print(f'your number is {randint(1,6)}')
    ques = input('Do you want to roll again !!')
else:
    print('Thank you For Playing')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
def dice_simulate():
    number = random.randint(1,6)
    print(number)
    while(1):
       flag = str(input("Do you want to dice it up again:Enter 1 and if not enter    0"))
       if flag == '1':
         number = random.randint(1,6)
         print(number)
      else:
         print("ending the game")
         return

dice_simulate()
```

For more understanding you can refre this: https://community.progress.com/code_share_group/f/169/t/35797

Comment: Do not use `while(1):`; Python idiom is to use `while True:`, `while` is not a function nor do Python compound statements use parentheses. You have 2 `random.randint()` calls in the code, that can trivially be reduced to one. This example is certainly no better than the other, earlier answers to this question.