# If statement is True but ELSE gets executed

Tags: python

This is a snippet from my script.

```
while True:

    ## Rules: userInput == [isalpha()=True, isdigit()=True, True, isdigit()=True]

    userInput = raw_input('# ').replace(' ', '').split(',')
    print userInput
    print 'List Index 0', userInput[0].isalpha()
    print 'List Index 1', userInput[1].isdigit()
    print 'List Index 3', userInput[3].isdigit()
    print 'List is', userInput[0].isalpha() and userInput[1].isdigit() and userInput[3].isdigit()

    if userInput[0].isalpha() and userInput[1].isdigit() and userInput[3].isdigit() == False:
        print 'Error'
        continue
    else:
        print 'Success'
        break
```

And this is the output I get if I run it with input: `1,1,1,1`

```
# 1,1,1,1
['1', '1', '1', '1']
List Index 0 False
List Index 1 True
List Index 3 True
List is False
Success
```

As far as I know the `if` statement is `True` and should be executed and return to the beginning of the loop until the rules are satisfied. However, the `else` statement gets executed instead.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you may be assuming that `if condition1 and condition2 == False` is the same thing as `if (condition1 and condition2) == False`, when it's actually the same thing as `if condition1 and (condition2 == False)`.

Comment: your if statement reads `if False and True and True` which is false, I'd bet it is exactly as Kevin says

Comment: Thank you!!! putting the if statement in brackets worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be assuming that `if condition1 and condition2 == False` is the same thing as `if (condition1 and condition2) == False`, when it's actually the same thing as `if condition1 and (condition2 == False)`.

In which case you should be doing

```
if (userInput[0].isalpha() and userInput[1].isdigit() and userInput[3].isdigit()) == False:
```

or

```
if not (userInput[0].isalpha() and userInput[1].isdigit() and userInput[3].isdigit()):
```

or

```
if userInput[0].isalpha() and userInput[1].isdigit() and userInput[3].isdigit():
    print 'Success'
    break
else:
    print 'Error'
    continue
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. Those damn brackets took away 2 hours of my life lmao

Answer (score 1):

Your Boolean logic is wrong, this:

```
userInput[0].isalpha() and userInput[1].isdigit() and userInput[3].isdigit() == False
```

boils down to:

```
False and True and True == False
```

and that is

```
False and True and False
```

which is `False`, not `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should change the statement of `while True` to something similar like `while 1:pass`. More information is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815359/while-1-vs-for-whiletrue-why-is-there-a-difference)